# How to see the feature list of a product using the stripe API?

Tags: javascript, firebase, stripe-payments

I have a stripe account where I have listed a few products. I noticed I can also list the product features from the stripe console:
[image: feature list]

Using the stripe api, I would like to grab this list from the product details and use it in the UI I am building. But I cannot see if this is possible

I have looked at the docs and I have not found anything talking about this feature list. Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible?

I apologize if am just blind and missed the docs somehow.

btw, I am using the stripe extension for firebase, but I think my underlying question about the stripe API applies just the same, no matter how I set up my backend.

Comment: These are dashboard only feature, they aren't accessible via API. Here what you can retrieve from product APIs https://stripe.com/docs/api/products. 
You can set these "features" as metadata so that you can retrieve them from the API.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I cannot get to this data from the API, using the metadata field sounds like my next best option. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem on my project.

From my research, it is not possible to get feature list with stripe api.

So we can use `metadata` instead of `feature list`.

It is surely possible to get `metadata` with stripe api.

If anyone has a better idea, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

They should be accessible now. I saw they did an update in java api client on this specific thing.

Comment: Do you have a reference to that update? I'm not seeing it anywhere in the API docs https://stripe.com/docs/api/products

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object#product_object-features